# How to show "Please wait" dialog until completion of a while loop?

Tags: java, swing, csv

I want to show a "Please Wait" dialog box until my application is importing to database from a csv file using a while loop. So the dialog box should stay, starting when the while loop begins and disappear when the while loop has finished execution.

Here is my code -

```
try{
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("temp.csv"));
    String line;
    line=br.readLine();
    while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
        String[]value = line.split(",");
        String sql = "INSERT into main ([Ticket #], Status, Priority, Department, [Account Name]) "
        + "values ('"+value[0]+"','"+value[1]+"','"+value[2]+"','"+value[3]+"','"+value[4]+"')";
        System.out.println(sql);
        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        try{
            pst = db.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.executeUpdate();
        }finally{
            if(pst != null){
                pst.close();
            }
        }
    }
    br.close();
} catch(Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

Comment: You need to learn about the [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) API.

Comment: I promise I will! But right now I need help with this. I'm presenting this to a VP in like 3 hours!

Comment: "This is really urgent" is not an excuse to demand free code. If you want something done pay someone. This is a Q&A site...

Comment: Relax Boris Becker! I'm saying please

Comment: What @BoristheSpider means is that posting that your question *is urgent* and any *please* or related comments are not a matter for us. Note that this site is to free help and you already got it from the first comment, but you insist to get your work done. There are other sites where you can pay to get the work done within a limited amount of time that is better suited for your case.

Comment: Really? Where are such websites? Can you please tell me one?

Comment: You'll fail examns if you don't think yourself ;)

Comment: @verbose-mode Ends justify means

Answer (score 0):

You need to have additional  worker thread to do your job. After you have started it, you will show dialog window in main thread. When it has finished it has to notify the main thread that the work is over and that it can hide the dialog window. If this is `Swing`, for this you can use (and it's preferred) `SwingWorker`. It is relatively easy. Simple example with explanation can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html). If you have problems understanding that tutorial then you need to study some basics about multi-threading and copy-paste code will not help you.